# Angular 2 RouterLink to rewrited URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, angular

Assuming I have PlayerProfile Component and I am using the following expression to allow user access this component:

`[routerLink]="['PlayerProfile',{name:activity.user.username}]"`

The URL is: `http://localhost:3000/player-profile?name=My Name`

But what if.. I want to make cleaner URL, like this:

`http://localhost:3000/player-profile/My Name`

What's the way to do it with angular 2 app? With my experience with web I tried to add the following into my .htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^player-profile/(.*)?$ player-profile&name=$1 [L]`

but it's not working (shows an empty route component) and also everytime I will use RouterLink the browser will show the `?name=..`.

So, What's the right way to do it in Angular 2?

Comment: What Angular2 version and what router version are you using? Routing is mostly client-side only, therefore server settings will not bring you far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router supports parameters

```
{path: 'player-profile/:name', component: PlayerProfile}
```

```
[routerLink]="['/player-profile/' + 'My Name']"
```

Comment: Any idea how to use that for 2 parameters divided by "-" (not a slash)? *For example: 1-Username*

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Redirecting to user profile will show the `username` in the URL, but the `userID` will be passed to the component too (so I can use it for my API call). If it required the `userID` to show in the URL, so the `username `and the `userID` both need should appear in the URL. Same as the following example link: `website.com/users/323-Gunter` or just `website.com/users/Gunter`